# LambdaJ forEach set

Tags: java, collections, lambdaj

I want to set value to a field of an object so that it will first get the previous value of that field and append something to it and the set it to that field.

In LambdaJ `forEach` we can do something like this:

`forEach(myCollection).setFieldValue("someValue");`

But what I need is:

`forEach(myCollection).setFieldValue(getFieldValue() + "someValue");`

Is it possible in LambdaJ?

Answer (score 4):

I know you asked about LambdaJ, I was curious to do that since it is a common problem.

I was surprised of the result I got doing:

```
forEach(list).setName(on(User.class).getName() + "someValue");
```

I though it would be the answer to your question.

So, I tried a different approach by using Guava functional way. It can work for you so I'll post the answer (but I can delete it if you don't agree with it):

Guava functional approach:

```
    @Test
    public void test_applyPreviousValue() {

         List<User> filteredList = Lists.newArrayList(new User("Fede", 20), new User("Peter", 12), new User("John", 41));

         Function<User, User> getType = new Function<User, User>() {
             public User apply(User input) {
                  input.setName(input.getName()+"someValue");
                  return input;
             }
         };

         Collection<User> result = Collections2.transform(filteredList, getType);
         System.out.println(result);
     }
```

Hope to help

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar usecase and realized forEach won't help the way I used it.

So I thought closures are a solution:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Closure modify = closure();{
        of(Point.class).setLocation(var(Point.class).x+10, 10);          
    }

    List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
    points.add(new Point(10, 0));
    points.add(new Point(10, 10));

    modify.each(points);

    for (Point point : points) {
        assertEquals(20, point.getX(), 0.0);
    }
}
```

But the asserts fails since the object in the collection is not been modified. Maybe I'm doing something wrong there.

In the end I used closures from the apache commons collection.

**UPDATE**

I was able to solve the puzzle with a closure. Looks like you can't use the free variable direct. Here is the working code:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Closure modify = closure();{
        of(this).visit(var(Point.class));
    }

    List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    points.add(new Point(10, 0));
    points.add(new Point(10, 10));

    modify.each(points);

    for (Point point : points) {
        assertEquals(20, point.getX(), 0.0);
    }
}

void visit(Point p) {
    p.setLocation(p.x + 10, p.y);
}
```

Note: instead of `this` you can also write a class which contains the `visit` method and use it in the definition of the `closure`.

Comment: I used commons collection too.

Comment: I came across a snippet, which made me looking at the problem again .. this time I was able to change the value of the free variable;-)